# Create SFTP User to connect and chroot it to only one subfolder ( using public , private key authentication instead of password

Tags: server, ssh, authentication, sftp

I have Ubuntu 16.04 server and i need to create a user account on the server which connect via sftp and must be restricted to one specific folder inside the Home directory.

I will need to use the public private key authentication for user to authenticate with server instead of password.

thats what i have done.

- Created the User account.
- created .ssh directory with inside the home directory of user.

mkdir -p ~/.ssh

- copy the public key of the remote client which will be connecting my
  server inside the `.ssh` directory.
- created the another Directory inside the home folder.

  mkdir -p ~/allowed-for-sftp-connection
- and from the remote host i can easily make the connection to ubuntu
  server but with this connection i can as well see the content of
  `.ssh` directory which i don't want.

can someone please help me out , how can i get this task done.

Comment: You should use the `Subsystem sftp internal-sftp` option of SSH. Take a look at [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134425/how-can-i-chroot-sftp-only-ssh-users-into-their-homes) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/805924/how-to-set-up-a-writeable-sftp-chroot). I have a smiliar setup. Just make sure that the groups and ownership are correct.

Comment: @RobertRiedl: thank you for your the links, I could manage to chroot the user to specific directory within the home directory but i still have issue with ssh key based authentication.